# How to select all users for which given parameters are always true

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing users and locations where they were seen:

```
user_id  | latitude | longitude | date_seen
-------------------------------------------
1035     | NULL     | NULL      | April 25 2010
1035     | 127      | 35        | April 28 2010
1038     | 127      | 35        | April 30 2010
1037     | NULL     | NULL      | May 1 2010
1038     | 126      | 34        | May 21 2010
1037     | NULL     | NULL      | May 24 2010
```

The dates are regular timestamps in the database; I just simplified them here.

I need to get a list of the users for whom latitude and longitude are always null. So in the above example, that would be user 1037--user 1035 has one row with lat/lon information, and 1038 has two rows with lat/lon information, whereas for user 1037, in both rows the information is null.

What query can I use to achieve this result?

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct user_id
from table_name t
where not exists(
    select 1 from table_name t1 
    where t.user_id = t1.user_id and 
    t1.latitude is not null and
    t1.longitude is not null
)
```

You can read this query: give me all users that haven't set lat and long different than `null` in any row in table. In my opinion `exists` is preferred in such case (no exists) because even if table scan is used (not optimal way to find row) it stops just after it finds specific row (there is no need to `count` all rows).

Read more about this topic: [Exists Vs. Count(*) - The battle never ends...](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx) .

Comment: +1 for using EXISTS and for providing the link. Just found http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg30397.html as a slight syntactical improvement turning *(SELECT 1 FROM..* into *(SELECT NONE FROM..* to emphasize, that you're not interested in any specific return value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work.

```
    SELECT user_id, count(latitude), count(longitude) 
    FROM user_loc 
    GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(latitude)=0 AND count(longitude)=0;
```

tested in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE latitude IS NULL AND longitude IS NULL;
```

-- Edit --

2nd try (untested, but constructed it from a query I have used before):

```
SELECT user_id, CASE WHEN MIN(latitude) IS NULL AND MAX(latitude) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS noLatLong FROM user GROUP BY user_id HAVING noLatLong = 1;
```

Comment: Won't that merely return all the rows where both the latitude and longitude are null? So, from above, it would return row 1 as well as rows 4 and 6, whereas I don't want row 1 returned because that user has a latitude and longitude provided in row 2.

Comment: True, it just returns the lines with missing lat/lon records; not eliminating dups nor user_ids with *at least one* record.

Comment: @Catherine: Sorry, I misunderstood. There are a couple of other posts since my correction, which may work, but offered up an alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT user_id
FROM    table
WHERE   latitude  IS NULL
    AND longitude IS NULL
    AND NOT user_id IN
        (SELECT  DISTINCT user_id
         FROM    table
         WHERE   NOT latitude  IS NULL
             AND NOT longitude IS NULL)
```

result:

```
1037
```

(syntax validated with SQLite here)

BUT: Even if not using COUNT here, my statement has to scan all table lines, so Michał Powaga's statement is more efficient.

rationale:

- get list of user_ids with lat/lon records to compare against (you want to EXCLUDE these from final result) - optimization: use EXISTS here...
- get list of user_ids without lat/lon records (that you're interested in)
- reduce by all IDs, that exist in the first list - optimization: use EXISTS here...
- make user_ids DISTINCT, because the example shows multiple entries per user_id (but you want just the unique IDs)